# SQLite Stops at 252 Entries

Tags: c++, sqlite

So I've written some C++ code to select data from one database and `INSERT` it into another. There's over 50,000 entries in the source db. The table definitions for the destination database are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE evidence_master
( id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    person_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    message TEXT,
    eid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    frequency INTEGER,
    string TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT eid_fk FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES evidences(eid)
);

CREATE TABLE evidences
(
    eid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    evidence_name TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT eid_pk PRIMARY KEY (eid)
);
```

The source database is the one found here: http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg/SMSCorpus/

My problem is, when it gets to the 252nd entry, it claims it cannot open the database (EDIT: the destination database). Despite having performed the work on 251 entries successfully.

Why might this be happening?

EDIT: here's the code that selects from the source:

```
dbOpenFail=sqlite3_open("../../../db/smscorpus.db", &dbCorpus);
if(dbOpenFail)
{
    cerr << "Can't open sms corpus: " << sqlite3_errmsg(dbCorpus);
}

if(sqlite3_prepare(dbCorpus, 
    queryCorpus.data(), 
    queryCorpus.length() + 1, 
    &preparedCorpusQuery, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    cerr << "Failed to prepare corpus query: " << queryCorpus << zErrMsg << endl;
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}
rowSelectCorpus=sqlite3_step(preparedCorpusQuery);
while(rowSelectCorpus != SQLITE_DONE)  //need to go through 51652 messages from corpus
{
    if(rowSelectCorpus == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        personID = sqlite3_column_text(preparedCorpusQuery, 0); //get sender ID
        messageContent = sqlite3_column_text(preparedCorpusQuery, 1); //get message itself
        db_entry d1(string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(personID)), 
            string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(messageContent)));
        insertResult = d1.insertIntoDatabase();
        if(insertResult == -1)
        {
            return 0; //exit
        }

    }
    rowSelectCorpus=sqlite3_step(preparedCorpusQuery);
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like for selecting data?

Comment: I'll edit my question to add the loop.

Comment: Does row 252 violate any of your constraints?

Comment: Why would that return an error that says "can't open database"?
I should note that it's the destination database that won't open.

Comment: I just checked row 252, I see nothing out of the ordinary for it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some C runtime libraries have a default limit of 256 open file handles per process.

Apparently, your program is opening the database for every `INSERT` operation, and forgets to close it.

You should open every database only once.

Comment: I was closing the database, or at least I was trying to, but I wasn't finalizing my prepared statements so it wasn't actually closing properly.
With the finalizing statement, the code works now. Thanks for pointing this out!